# How to set passwordless session with x2go

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, x2go, x2goclient

I have set up private/public keys between a client and a server.
I can do passwordless ssh logins.

I use x2go to establish remote desktop sessions from the client, with the following configuration:

[image]

However, I'm unable to achieve a passwordless login as described in  https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:advanced:authentication:passwordless-ssh

After being prompted for the passhprase, I still get prompted for the user password.
[image]

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [documentation wiki](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:advanced:authentication:passwordless-ssh) is outdated.
It states (bold emphasis is mine):

> After the transfer **you can add the path to the private part of the key**
> to the session preferences inside x2goclient. x2goclient should now
> establish the connection without asking for a password by simply
> clicking on the session card view.

Instead, only setting the option `Try auto login` is actually required.
the field `Use RSA/DSA key for ssh connection` must be left empty.

[image]